# how to reorder columns in my df by date order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to order my df so that the columns go from 2008 to 2011.

```
date_order = oval_df.columns.sort_values(ascending=True)
oval_df = oval_df.reindex(columns=[date_order])
```

If I do the following code I get

[image]

where it should reflect but with the correct order

date_order returns:

```
Index(['Dec. 31, 2008', 'Dec. 31, 2009', 'Dec. 31, 2009A', 'Dec. 31, 2010',
   'Dec. 31, 2010A', 'Dec. 31, 2011'],
  dtype='object')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get a list of all columns by

```
cols = df.columns
```

and then reorder them by last element:

```
cols_new = sorted(cols, key=lambda x: x.split(' ')[-1])
```

now your `cols` are ordered in `cols_new`.

Comment: how do i implement that in my code? I got the same errors as above when I tried to use oval_df.reindex(columns=[cols_new])

Comment: do you mean `df_new=df[cols_new]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you just have 7 numbers of columns why don't you sort manually like:

```
oval_df=oval_df[['Dec. 31, 2008', 'Dec. 31, 2009', 'Dec. 31, 2009A', 'Dec. 31, 2010', 'Dec. 31, 2010A', 'Dec. 31, 2011']]
```

and you can don't have to type all, you can access the columns name with help of pandas library, the code will be `df.columns`

Comment: Because its gotta be dynamic as I will be using for multiple years this is  just a test scenario this company has like 20 years of data